# Activity indicator view in table cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a table, I want to make it so that when I click on a cell, the activity indicator spins around it, and not somewhere in an incomprehensible place

[image]

It looks like this. In the code, I have the MainViewController module and the Presenter module which determines when to start the activity indicator. I have an outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView! = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
```

I have two functions in the view controller that start the animation and stop

```
func startActivity() {
   activity.startAnimating()
}


func stopActivity() {
   activity.stopAnimating()
}
```

there is a function that handles a click on a cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
   output.callFromThePresenter(array: array[indexPath.row])

}
```

This function is implemented in the presenter.

```
func callFromThePresenter(array: String) {

  let userInteractiveQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)

  async {
    DispatchQueue.main.async  {
        self.view.startActivity()
    }
    userInteractiveQueue.async {
         self.interactor.functionFromInteractor(data: array)
    }
  }
}
```

as I assumed, in the view controller, when you click on a cell, the callFromThePresenter () function will work, and the animation function and the data transfer function in the Interactor will start in it, as soon as the Interactor has completed this function, it will return the data to the Presenter and inside the call back function, I will run the stopActivity () function. And it worked until I decided to set the positioning

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
   output.callFromThePresenter(array: array[indexPath.row])
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
   cell?.accessoryView = self.activity
}
```

as soon as i added these two lines

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell?.accessoryView = self.activity
```

I broke everything, as if I started up, I click on the table cell and the wheel turns where it is needed and everything works, but after receiving the result, I poke at some cell again, the whole program hangs, and I don’t know for what reason . At the same time, the functions work out how much I can understand it, because it comes to the console that the function was launched and got some result, but then the whole UI hangs tight and I can't do anything

Comment: It looks like you have **one** `UIActivityIndicatorView` for **multiple** cells. This cannot work. And consider that modifying a cell in `didSelectRowAt` is not persistent. Cells are reused. And the declaration `array: String` is very confusing.

Comment: @vadian , Yes, I have one, but the problem is that I don’t know how to do it right with a few and how to do it right

Comment: Create a **custom** cell with the `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside. Add a property `isRunning` to your data model. Start/stop the indicator view in `cellForRow` depending on `isRunning`. If your task stops set `isRunning` to false and reload the corresponding row to stop the indicator.

Comment: @vadian, did not quite understand, but I will try

Comment: I wrote an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

- In Interface Builder set the `Style` of the table view cell to `custom`.
- Drag a label and an activity indicator into the cell and set appropriate constraints if needed.
- Select the activity indicator, press <kbd>⌘⌥4</kbd> (Attributes Inspector) and check *Hides When Stopped*.
- Create a custom class, a subclass of `UITableViewCell` in the project

  ```
  class TitleCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

      var isRunning : Bool = false {
          didSet {
              isRunning ? activity.startAnimating() : activity.stopAnimating()
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Set the class of the prototype cell in Interface Builder to `TitleCell` and connect the label and the indicator to the `IBOutlets`
- Create a data model with at least a `title` and a `isRunning` property.

  ```
  struct Model {
      let title: String
      var isRunning : Bool
  }
  ```
- Declare a data source array

  ```
  var items = [Model]()
  ```
- In `cellForRow` update the UI elements (replace the identifier with your real identifier)

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TitleCell
      let item = items[indexPath.row]
      cell.titleLabel!.text = item.title
      cell.isRunning = item.isRunning
      return cell
  }
  ```
- To start and stop the indicator implement `didSelectRow`

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
      items[indexPath.row].isRunning.toggle()
      tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
  }
  ```

To change the state of the indicator use always the pattern to set `isRunning` in the model and reload the row.

Comment: I will suggest to override isSelected in TitleCell class to spin indicator.
`override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected {
            }
    }}`

Comment: @vadian, did not understand a little on this line  cell.isRunning = item.isRunning
cell has no access to .isRunning and he doesn’t even know what it is

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. The custom cell `TitleCell` has a `isRunning` property which starts and stops the indicator on change.

Comment: @vadian, Let me ask you something else, I did, as you indicated in the example, but I don’t quite understand one thing
in the didSelectRowAt () function, it calls tableView.reloadRows (at: [indexPath], with: .none)

Comment: @vadian, the problem is that the restart occurs only by clicking on the table cell, I can not figure out how to make the restart or update go after getting the result from the function output.callFromThePresenter (array: array [indexPath.row]), as in me in the example

Comment: @vadian, clicked a cell, didSelectRowAt processed this click, called output.callFromThePresenter (array: array [indexPath.row]) in the presenter, and started the animation inside this function when the result came by call back then the animation stopped

Comment: It's only an example. You need the index(path) of the array. To start the indicator set `isRunning` in the mode at given index to `true` and reload the row at given index path. To stop the indicator set `isRunning` in the model to `false` and reload the row.